# Comoving particle in FRLW metric

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, space-expansion

I don't know how to describe the motion of a comoving particle in the FRLW metric. I should also find the time that a comoving particle determines using the expression of the FLRW metric. How could I do it?

Comment: Try this book page 11-12 https://cmb.wintherscoming.no/pdfs/baumann.pdf

Comment: In [comoving coordinates](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/25.html) the spatial coordinates x,y,z of a comoving particle  are constant and the proper time τ is the same as the coordinate time t, and for proper distance coordinates see [here](http://yukterez.rf.gd/f/einstein.equations/files/35.html)  at Output 14